# Why sometimes I see an arrow function and other just the the function on event handlers in react?

Tags: reactjs

Sometimes I see this on a react handler:

`<Results onClick={() => this.somefunction()}/>`

and other times like:

`<Results onChange={this.handleChange} />`

What is the mail difference on these ways of writing the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first example `somefunction` doesn't need to worry about having access to the wrong `this`: it will refer to the instance of the class that's defined in.

Your second example *may* not have the same certainly, depending on how's defined: you will need to bind the function or use arrow functions.

The actual react documentation provide more insight on this: https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

Also: referential identity. The first example create a new function on every render. It may mess up with pure component, because the props will keep changing. The second example pass always the same function: pure component will see them as the same props as before and won't re-render unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

The former 'hoists' the `someFunction` in a callback to be ran at a later time. The latter looks for the code in `handleChange` immediately.

Also, you have the context issue with `this`. In an arrow function, `this` doesn't attach context to the function itself, but rather to the parent context. In essence, `this` would have the same context in each of these examples.